# Regarding the listing feature of Snowflake Data Share

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I see an ambiguous content in the snowflake documentation. In the guide, https://docs.snowflake.com/guides-overview-sharing#options-for-sharing, it says all listings use auto cloud fulfillment. But then in the link https://other-docs.snowflake.com/en/collaboration/provider-listings-managing.html#managing-consumer-listing-requests, it says that not all listings are auto cloud fulfilment. Only private listing and paid listings are auto cloud fulfilled.

Can anyone please clarify which of these about listings is true

Comment: You’re probably better off asking this question to Snowflake Support - if the documentation is unclear/contradictory then you can only get opinions in this forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All listings (except personalized listings) can use auto-fulfillment. Private and paid listings are required to use auto-fulfillment for cross-region fulfillment.

Thanks for this feedback - the team is now aware that the docs need this improvement.